# Rails 3 app throws "undefined method `update_attributes'" on save

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller a whole bunch of numbers are crunched. Percentages are multiplied by 100 so they can be stored as integers.

```
tot = @mot[1] + @mot[2] + @mot[3]
exec_pct = @mot[3] / tot * 100
tact_pct = @mot[2] / tot * 100
strat_pct = @mot[1] / tot * 100
```

Then the values are supposed to be written to the user record as follows:

```
@user = User.where(id = current_user.id)
@user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => strat_pct.to_i, :tact_pct => tact_pct.to_i, :exec_pct => exec_pct.to_i )
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `update_attributes'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you to remove these operations from your controller and to put them inside a callback method of your user model. (before_save for instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
@user = User.where(id = current_user.id)
```

In the above, you are doing an assignment to the variable id to the value of current_user.id which is not your intention in this case.

If you do:

```
p @user.class
```

Then it will return nilClass.

You need either:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

Or:

```
@user = User.where(:id => current_user.id)
```

Although based on your code, current_user is probably an instance of User.  I would say you don't need to make any additional calls, you should be able to do:

```
current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => strat_pct.to_i, :tact_pct => tact_pct.to_i, :exec_pct => exec_pct.to_i )
```